# valueHelpOnly for smart filter bar in sapui5

Tags: javascript, sapui5, sap-fiori

I have included smartFilterBar:ControlConfiguration control in Smart Filter Bar. One of the controls has F4 value help. In this control, I can enter some text manually also. How can I disable entering the text and display value help dialog only on click of that filed. In short I want a feature similar to "valueHelpOnly" in Input field which disable manual entry of data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Programatically you can do it in a following way:

```
myControl = this.getView().byId("smartFilterBar").getControlByKey("myControl")
myControl.setValueHelpOnly(true);
```

After that, clicking on selection field will automatically open the value help dialog.